# using regex to replace unknown text

Tags: regex, vim

Say I have the following code

```c
int func1(int a);
int func2(int a);
int func3(int a);
```

Using vim search and replace, I want to turn it into this

```c
/* This function handles action 1*/
int func1(int a);
/* This function handles action 2 */
int func2(int a);
/* This function handles action 3 */
int func2(int a);
```

To search for each function is simple enough, I can simply do this
`/int func.`
But, I don't know how I can use the value of the . in the replace section. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Not having used vim, isn't it just the JS syntax? `/match/replacement/`?

Comment: But the problem is that the match includes unknown characters, and the replace will have to know them as well

Comment: (1) why do you want to add clearly redundant comments? (2) have you tried captures + `$0` / `$1` / `%0` / `%1`?

Comment: @LMD the question is specifically about Vim's regex dialect.

Comment: Shouldn't the first output line have a space before `*/` like the other lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use what is colloquially called "capture groups" (though Vim doesn't really have a name for that mechanism).

In Vim, you define a capture group by wrapping what you want to capture with escaped parentheses:

```
:%s/foo\(what you want to capture\)bar/what you want to capturebaz
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and you use it with an escaped number in the range 1-9 corresponding to the position of the capture group in the pattern:

```
:%s/foo\(what you want to capture\)bar/\1baz
                                       ^^
```

See `:h \(`.

In this specific case:

```
:%s/int func\(.\)/\/* This function handles action \1 *\/\r\0
```

where we even use `\0` which references the whole pattern.

Comment: To avoid unnecessary escapes of slashes, choose a separator other than `/`, say a `#`: `:%s#int func\(.\)#/* This function handles action \1 */\r\0`

Comment: @Bohemian two `#` versus two \: while it is a neat trick it is useless here.

Comment: @romaini it's not useless: makes the expression shorter and more readable - eg `http://` is easier to read than `http:\/\/`

Comment: Thanks! I did hear of capture groups in the past, but didn't think to use them here.